# How do I stop bad block errors in the event viewer when the RAID software reports no errors?

Tags: windows-server-2003, dell, hard-drive, hardware-raid, bad-blocks

Our Dell PowerEdge 2950 server has 4 SAS disks in a RAID 5 array on a Dell PERC 6/i SCSI card.  We are running Windows 2003 SBS R2 - 32 bit.  SP2.

> The device, \Device\Harddisk0, has a bad block.

The above error is logged numerous time in the event logs over a period of months, many times each day.

The Dell diagnostics all come back clean showing no errors of any kind.  Dell technical support have checked while remotely connected to the server and also failed to see anything caused by the hardware.

CHKDSK comes back with nothing.

We are hitting our head against a brick wall in what to check next.  Although we have seen no crashes or other symptoms, we are obviously concerned and want to prevent any problems before they have chance to surface.

Any input, suggestions or experiences of the same kind of thing would be really appreciated in trying to get this fixed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try updating your controller's firmware and Windows drivers to the latest releases of both.

Also, try this one: [KB932755](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/932755); for some reason, even if it is ***critical*** to proper operation of many storage drivers, it was never released on Windows Update.

Comment: I second that. This wee b*gger took our cluster out every few weeks until we tracked it down.